# QGIS Server not serving / no log files

Tags: qgis, wms, server, log

I'm running QGIS server on Debian. It’s a virtual machine.

I already tried searching, but I found nothing, that helped me out.
What I did:

I installed QGIS Server and all needed packages. I can talk to the server via http, when I call this link:
http://IP/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi

Answer:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0">
    <ServiceException code="Service configuration error">Service unknown or unsupported</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

So far, so nice.

When I call:

```
http://IP/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/var/www/html/S5/qgis/test/qgis-demo/world3.qgs
```

I get:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0">
<ServiceException code="WMS configuration error">
There was an error reading the project file or the SLD configuration
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I set the rights to the Folder /var/www/html/S5/qgis and all Folders and files inside to 775 via chmod but I cant get it to work. I have no idea and I find no useful threads in the hole internet to help me out.

Problem 2 is, that qgis-server is not writing any logs.
For logs, I set up a config in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf
```

like this:

```
#Tell QGIS Server instances to use a specific display number for xvfb
# necessary for printing, see below
FcgidInitialEnv DISPLAY ":99"
# Activate QGIS log (different from apache logs)
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE /var/log/qgis/qgisserver.log
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL "0"
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_DEBUG 1
# Add a default QGIS project
#SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE /var/www/html/S5/qgis/qgis-demo.qgz
# QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH must lead to a directory writeable by www-data
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH "/var/www/qgis-server/qgisserverdb/"
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_PASSWORD_FILE "/var/www/qgis-server/qgisserverdb/qgis-auth.db"

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
# Longer timeout for WPS... default = 40
FcgidIOTimeout 120
FcgidMaxRequestLen 26214400
FcgidConnectTimeout 60
</IfModule
```

The owner of the logfile is www-data.
I set a # to comment the standard project file out to serve the WMS via the attribute MAP.

I tried other project as well, but its not working.
Can anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration below is working for me:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    LogLevel alert
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    ...
    FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL "0"
    FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgisserver.log
    FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_STDERR "1"
    ... 
    </IfModule>
    ...
    </VirtualHost>
```